# Installing Jelly Bean on China-made Ice Cream Sandwich tablet

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

I just bought this China-made tablet, **Flytouch**, and it has Ice Cream Sandwich installed on it.

Is there anyway to install Jelly Bean? I Googled some and couldn't find a good source. Do you know any? thanks

Answer (score -2):

I found this [forum thread](http://www.apad.tv/apadforum/showthread.php?3159-ibex-Flytouch-9-%2aNEW%2a-Firmware-VonDroid-N101-V4.0-%28Jelly-Bean-4.1.1%29) that tells you how to update the firmware to one that runs Jelly Bean (Android 4.1.1). It appears to be an update to a stock firmware update that came out for the tablet sometime last year.

**This does appear to require your tablet to be rooted**

Comment: ...and when that link stops working, what will be the value of this answer?

Comment: Downvoting is not the answer to that. The content of the link is far to long to post

Comment: That's a fairly short post that will easily fit here, but you could summarize it.  Most of it is cruft.